# Open an XML with a QTReport.exe

Tags: javascript, file-io, open-with

I am writing a Javascript code. In which I have to open an XML file with QTReport.exe. QTReport.exe is made up of to read the xml file and to show the QTP execution results. I am able to do the following in windows explorer. I did, right click on an XML file and choose the option "Open with" and specify the program as "C:\Bin\QTReport.exe".
My question is, is there any API or function that I can specify as open an XML file with QTReport.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command line arguement with the qtreport.exe:

```
bin_dir\qtreport.exe -r path_to_xml_file
```